# Any suggestions to get an Audio CD to load

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, optical-drive

I just purchased four albums with a total of 6 CDs.  Four of the CDs work just fine.  Two of them will not load on both of my laptops.  When I push them into the CD slot, I hear the drive spin up and down a few times and then the CD is kicked back out.

Both of the troublesome CDs work in my truck.  If it was just one, I'd assume it was just a bad CD but two out of six plus the fact that they work in my truck leads me to assume that Apple's software is goofed up somehow.

One laptop is an early 2007 15" MBP with 10.6.8.  The other laptop is early 2011 17" MBP with 10.7.5.  Both have the latest iTunes 11 and all of the updates, etc.

I tried even booting the 2007 MBP in safe mode but it had the same issue.  I've tried setting the CD / DVD preferences to various settings (e.g. ignore) but no change.

Has anyone else seen this?  Does anyone have a work around?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same pb with CD's or DVD's that are a little thicker than normally. Perhaps some sticker on top of the CD/DVD. In my case I was using CD who are labeled and my MBP. If you are using new CD then there is a quality pb with it.

Comment: I got a new USB CD/DVD drive and that solved my problem.  It was suggested to me by folks who use CDs a lot.  They said it sounded like bad CD drives.  It was hard for me to believe but it turns out that they were right.